# discord.js rank command for @user

Tags: sqlite, discord, discord.js

My rank command is working fine, iv been trying to add the ability to !rank @user. As you can see i have code there to grab the mentioned user, so it will display the mentioned users name and profile pic but my points (because they are requested from message.author) I'm just unsure how i should get the points from the database for the mentioned user. Any help or advice would be amazing, thanks!

(my database is SQLite)

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
    score = bot.getScore.get(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
    if (!score) {
      score = {
          id: `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`,
          user: message.author.id,
          guild: message.guild.id,
          points: 0,
          level: 1,
      };
  }
    let curxp = score.points;
    let curlvl = score.level;
    let nxtLvlXp = curlvl * 300;
    let difference = nxtLvlXp - curxp;
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("XP / LEVEL")
      .setDescription(member.user.tag)
      .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL)
      .setColor(cyan)
      .addField('**' + "Level" + '**', curlvl, true)
      .addField('**' + "XP" + '**', curxp, true)
      .setFooter(`${difference} XP til next level up`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);

    return message.channel.send({ embed });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much already have it

Instead of using `message.author.id` for the first argument why not just use the member variable which gives the final member?

Also you should have `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])` before message.member, since `message.member` will always exist unless in a DM Channel.

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
score = bot.getScore.get(member.id, message.guild.id);
```